# Pyradiomics: Feature class glcm is not recognized. How to fix it?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn, pyinstaller, medical

I am making a project with a GUI for liver ultrasound diagnostics.

I use PyQT5 (5.12.1) for GUI and sklearn (0.21.2) for statistics models. Main texture features I get from pyradiomics (2.2.0).

When I compile my project in PyCharm 2019.1 - all works completely fine.

But when I try to build my project as .exe file with pyinstaller, I got some erors. I solved most of them (about missing libraries) but this one left.

I got errors:

```
    Feature class firstorder is not recognized
    Feature class glcm is not recognized
    Feature class glrlm is not recognized
    Feature class ngtdm is not recognized
    Feature class glszm is not recognized
```

and my model also gives an error (when I fit my new data with models that were already saved in .sav files from sklearn):

```
ValueEror: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,3)(96,)(1,3)
```

1) I tried to change from:

```
    extractor.enableFeatureClassByName('glcm')
```

to:

```
    extractor.enableFeatureClassByName(str('glcm'))
```

It did not help.

2) Also I tried to build a project at different versions of pyradiomics:

2.1.1 and
2.2.0
give the same result (error)

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import pickle
    import sklearn
    ...
    folderName = "tmp"
    sl = "/"
    image_path_to = os.getcwd() + "/data/nrrd/" + folderName + sl + name_image
    label_path_to = os.getcwd() + "/data/nrrd/" + folderName + sl + name_label

    # Instantiate the extractor
    extractor = featureextractor.RadiomicsFeatureExtractor()

    # Switch on only needed feature class
    extractor.disableAllFeatures()
    extractor.enableFeatureClassByName('firstorder') <<< There is a problem
    extractor.enableFeatureClassByName('glcm')
    extractor.enableFeatureClassByName('glrlm')
    extractor.enableFeatureClassByName('ngtdm')
    extractor.enableFeatureClassByName('gldm')
    extractor.enableFeatureClassByName('glszm')

    # result -> ordered dict
    result = extractor.execute(image_path_to, label_path_to)
    df =  pd.DataFrame(result, index=[0])
    ...

    # Load the model from disk
    model_name = 'Multi-layer Perceptron'
    poolParam = ["diagnosis_code", "isnorm"]
    models = [0,5]
    for param in poolParam:
        filename = 'data/result/model/' + model_name + ' ' + param  + '.sav'
        file = open(filename, 'rb')
        loaded = pickle.load(file)
        print("Model <" + model_name + " " + param   + "> was loaded")

        # Test the classifier
        y_pred = int(loaded.predict(data)) <<< There is a problem
```

Comment: Please put your full error traceback.